# Need a Mouse with a scrollwheel, back browser shortcut button on the thumb side and forward shortcut button on the ring finger side

Tags: mice

I previously had an HP 5 button optical comfort mouse but these are now end of life for some reason with no apparent like-for-like replacement.

One 'slit' button each side meant no uncomfortable straining for the right button and kept things nice and simple. Today's range of mice seems to be vying with mobile phone handsets in the straining discomfort stakes.

Comment: Which hand are you using your mouse with?

Comment: Also, do you allow for software setup? E.g. you would be required to program which button is which in mouse vendor software before using it for the first time?

Comment: If you're OK with software programmable buttons, which OS does the mouse need to be compatible with?

Comment: @Romen usually those soft programmable mice have settings saved in the mouse itself. At least for the DPI, haven't tested it with buttons.

Comment: @JanDorniak, We still need to know which OS they will need, what good is the on-board memory if the software for programming it doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Romen I did stuff like programming the on-board memory on a friend's Windows machine when I had only Linux. Worked like a charm. My point is that one-off programming is way less of a hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

I use the ergonomic Adesso iMouse E1 — five buttons and scroll wheel.

https://www.adesso.com/product/imouse-e1-vertical-ergonomic-illuminated-mouse/

Mine is right-handed, but the iMouse E7-TAA is for left hands.

https://www.adesso.com/product/imouse-e7-taa-left-handed-vertical-ergonomic-mouse/